# Is there a way to maintain a global bloc that stores all the remaining bloc states information

Tags: flutter, bloc, streamcontroller

For my flutter project, iam dealing with multiple blocs each bloc have its own api data in its state, can i maintain a single bloc like a global thing, that contains all my states, apart from my individual blocs that gets triggered based on their initializations, and i want a global bloc that will collect all the states and gets notified whenever there is state change in any of the blocs.

can someone please help me with this, i am aware that we can use multibloc providers and can build my various parts of ui with bloc builders, but i want to achieve a global bloc, so that i can wrap my ui with the main global bloc, and initilize the remaining blocs from a page.

I had tried multibloc providers to use multiple blocs in projects and builds the ui components with respective blocs, but i want to achieve a global bloc that holds all the states information and should get notified whenever there is state change.